# Terraform read details of existing resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am facing an issue in terraform where I want to read details of some existing resource (r1) created via AWS web console.
I am using those details in creation on new resource (r2) via terraform.

Problem is that it is trying to destroy and recreate that resource which is not desired as it will be failed. How can I manage not to destroy and recreate r1 when I do terraform apply.

**Here is how I am doing it :**

main.tf

```
resource "aws_lb" "r1"{

}

...

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "r2" {

  type                    = "HTTP"
  uri                     = "${aws_lb.r1.dns_name}}/o/v1/multi/get/m/content"
}
```

first I import that resource

```
 terraform import aws_lb.r1 {my_arn}
```

next I apply terraform

```
terraform apply
```

error

```
 aws_lb.r1: Error deleting LB: ResourceInUse: Load balancer 'my_arn' cannot be deleted because it is currently associated with another service
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `lifecycle` configuration block in the `resource "aws_lb" "r1"` (see: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle) to tell Terraform to ignore changes in the resource.

I guess something like this should work:

```
resource "aws_lb" "r1"{

 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["*"]
  }
}
```

Comment: This only masks the problem the OP is facing and more importantly, poses the risk of deleting your ALB when removing the imported resource, for no benefit other than deriving its DNS name. Please see my post about using a `data source` instead.

Comment: The syntax has now changed, you should use `ignore_changes = all`.
Message from Terraform:
 The `["*"]` form of ignore_changes wildcard is was deprecated and is now invalid. Use `"ignore_changes = all"` to ignore changes to all attributes.

Comment: Tiemen's answer is the correct answer.  Tiemen's comment in the accepted answer about his answer being correct and the acceoted amswer leading to more trouble is also correct.

Answer (score 21):

The `import` statement is [meant for taking control over existing resources in your Terraform setup](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/).

If your only intention is to derive information on existing resources (outside of your Terraform control), [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/lb.html) are designed specifically for this need:

```
data "aws_lb" "r1" {
    name = "lb_foo"
    arn = "some_specific_arn" #you can use any selector you wish to query the correct LB
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "r2" {
    type = "HTTP"
    uri = "${data.aws_lb.r1.dns_name}/o/v1/multi/get/m/content"
}
```

Comment: that was useful, but it didn't work with resource of type aws_api_gateway_vpc_link

Comment: @HimanshuGoel Could you please clarify? I might be able to assist.